# What happens when two processes wait for the same child?

Tags: c, fork, waitpid

From what I've read the default behavior for `wait`/`waitpid` is to wait for a state change in a process. What I can't find is the expected behavior of two processes `waitpid` using the same `pid_t` argument.

Do both return and continue execution, or is it a race condition where only one notices the state change?

Comment: How can two processes have the same child?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the parent can wait() for a process, and a process can of course have only one parent.

The parent process might, however, have multiple threads.  In the case of multiple threads waiting for the same child, POSIX specifies that only one of them will see the state change.  To allow multiple threads to see the state change, you must use waitid() with the WNOWAIT flag.

[POSIX: status information](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_13)

Comment: Nitpicking: "*Only the parent can wait() for a process*" Any process could (call) wait, but *only the parent* would do so successfully.